# Register Grunt tasks without grunt.initConfig()

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I want my gruntfile.js to be naturally structured so that micro-tasks follow each other one by one.
Suppose I have the following structure:

```js
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    clean: {
        movedTyping: 'options...'
    },
    copy: {
        typing: 'options...',
        lessVariables: 'options...',
        html: 'options...'
    },
    less: {
        compile: 'options...'
    },
    typescript: {
        compile: 'options...'
    }
});


grunt.registerTask('build', [
    // TYPESCRIPT
    'typescript:compileSingle',
    'copy:typing',
    'clean:movedTyping',

    // LESS
    'less:compile',
    'copy:lessVariables',

    // HTML
    'copy:html'
]);
```

But I would like to achieve the other structure:

```js
grunt.registerTask('build', function () {
    // TYPESCRIPT
    grunt.task.run('typescript', 'options...');
    grunt.task.run('copy', 'options...');
    grunt.task.run('clean', 'options...');

    // LESS
    grunt.task.run('less', 'options...');
    grunt.task.run('copy', 'options...');

    // HTML
    grunt.task.run('copy', 'options...');
});
```

How?

Comment: On a side note.You will like [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set properties of the object by using . (dot) notation. So nested structure data can also be set. I haven't come across a more cleaner approach and will be happy to see a better approach.

```
grunt.registerTask('build', function () {
   // TYPESCRIPT
   grunt.config.set('typescript.compile','<options>');
   grunt.task.run('typescript');

   ......................
});
```

Comment: It works and looks simple. So pity that I have spent an hour for my solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/29415472/4137472

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this I created NPM module [create-grunt-tasks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-grunt-tasks).
Now my grunt file looks like this:

```
// Gruntfile.js 
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    require('create-grunt-tasks')(grunt, function (create) {
        create.task('build')
            // Compile TypeScript and move typing 
            .sub('typescript', {
                src: 'src/index.ts',
                dest: 'build/index.js',
                options: { module: 'amd', target: 'es5', declaration: true }
            })
            .sub('copy', {
                expand: true, flatten: true,
                src: 'build/index.d.ts',
                dest: 'build/typing/index.d.ts'
            })
            .sub('clean', ['build/index.d.ts'])
            // Copy HTML 
            .sub('copy', {
                expand: true, flatten: true,
                src: 'src/index.html',
                dest: 'build/index.html'
            });
    });
}
```